# Gradle dependency management control (development and Distribution mode)

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

Good day everyone! First of all, I'm sorry about the poor title. I don't know how to describe my question precisely. I have a current build.gradle like this:

```
/*** Gradle build file for ProjectA ***/

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'ivy-publish'

sourceCompatibility=1.6

group = 'no.sample.project.client'
version='2.0.4.7'


repositories {
    ivy {
        url "K://development/shared-libs/ivy2"
    }

    mavenCentral();
}

dependencies {
//  compile project(':ProjectB')
//  compile project(':ProjectC')
//  compile project(':ProjectD')
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4+'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1+'
    compile 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.0+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4+'
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.3'
    compile 'com.miglayout:miglayout-swing:4.2'
    compile 'org.swinglabs:swingx:1.6.1'
    compile 'com.jgoodies:jgoodies-common:1.7.0'
    compile 'com.jgoodies:jgoodies-binding:2.10.0'
    compile 'no.sample.project.common:ProjectB:1.0.3.0'
    compile 'no.sample.project.common:ProjectC :1+'
    compile 'no.sample.project.client:ProjectD:2.+'
    compile 'org.tigris.gef:gef:0.13.8'
//  compile files('tmpLib/gef-0.13.8.jar')
}

// Defines what and where to publish.
publishing {
    publications {
        ivyJava(IvyPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }

    repositories {
        ivy {
              url "K://development/shared-libs/ivy2"
        }
    }

//xlint . has something to do with javaCompile
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation" << "-Xlint:unchecked"
    }
}
}
```

ProjectA is being used by other projects (example ProjectF), and the problem arise when we need to debug. Let's say ProjectF has an error and the error is in ProjectA. We don't get access to the ProjectA directly since it's a jar, and we can't attach the source code when we deploy neither. (We don't want to give the source code to the clients of course. )  What I want to achieve is that we add the ProjectA itself as the dependency when we're working with / debugging ProjectF (Development) , but publish the project with the only ProjectA's JAR file as dependency.

I hope I have been clear enough and please don't hesitate to ask anything.

PS.

An edit to this question might be really helpful. I'm just poor at explaining and giving a good title.